# Paypal put funds on hold

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I am an iOS developer working on a mobile app

Our app business model is based on creating a niche marketplace between users. i.e a user can request a service and any user can provide the service and get payed by the requester.

We want to prevent misuse of the app by rouge users.
We want to create a user license agreement that will state then once the user submitted a new request to the marketplace with a specific amount then in case all of the criteria will be fulfilled later on - the app will complete the transfer.

Is there an option to put paypal funds on hold to be freezed/ unfreezed later on via the mobile idk/ backend server ?

If a user consents for a future payment, does it guarantee the availability of the funds later on?

Which Paypal API should I use?

Thank you,
Shai

Comment: One option will be to create your own PayPal account as a mediator between the buyer and seller. i.e. When buyer pays, the money goes to your PayPal, then after 15/20 days of hold, can be transferred from your PayPal to the seller's. Granted there will be some additional transaction costs, but you'll of course have more control over the transfer of funds.

Comment: Also, if you want to avoid the transaction costs, you can pass it on to the buyer/seller/both. I think the major market places like Upwork, Envato, etc. do it the same way.